# Changing the timezone on the fly

Tags: php, timezone

I have a small php server side app where the user is allowed to change their timezone. I have set the default timezone in the ini file but will need to change this on the fly so that I can pass the user defined time into a database query to get the proper results. What might be the best way to handle this? Should I be using date_default_timezone_set()?

EDIT: Is this a difficult task or haven't I explained what I need well enough?

Comment: You tagged php but talk about an 'app'. Are you writing a server side application with multiple users or a desktop application with just one user? If the latter, why are you using php?

Comment: I wrote a server side application that parses documents. There is no user interaction what so ever with the exception of being able to change their timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) as needed.  Is that too easy?

Comment: :) It almost seems too easy and that was why I wanted to ask. I thought I needed to do some translations between my ini timezone and the user defined timezone. Am I correct in saying that PHP will automatically change this when I use date_default_timezone_set?

Comment: One thing that may be a problem: dates stored in your database.  They should be in UTC so there's no doubt.  This means, before storing convert to UTC and after retrieving covert from.  Is that an issue here?

Comment: I'm talking about MySQL DATETIME data types here.  That way, MySQL stores and retrieves exactly the value you give.

Comment: hmm.. I'm not following you on this Derek. Here has always been my issue with mysql and how it stores times where it pertains to user defined timezones. I have yet to figure out how to set a timezone in mysql on a per user basis. Can you provide an example? Also... date_default_timezone_set is a PHP function so how does this tie into mysql?

Comment: Jim, this was tricky for me.  Now, my DATETIME columns are named like `date_utc` or `starts_utc`, then when saving in PHP I convert my date to UTC.  That way, I don't care about MySQLs timezone setting, because I'm giving and getting UTC.  PHP ties into MySQL because they're handing date strings back and forth and they both need to interpret those properly.  In my case, MySQL interprets it as string data (basically, just leaving it alone), PHP interprets it as a UTC date.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I may have to do the same thing. I have yet to figure out a solid way of handling this myself.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one pattern:

1. Store Timezone per user (e.g. the string $userTimezone = 'America/Los_Angeles').
2. Set the timezone for the MySQL connection session

   Issue this MySQL command before any CRUD statements:

   > "SET SESSION time_zone=$userTimezone ;"
3. Store a date-time (provided in the user's timezone) in a MySQL TIMESTAMP field (which internally stores in UTC - it will do the conversion for you, based on MySQL session time_zone, upon storing and retrieving).
4. When you SELECT (as long as SET SESSION has already been issued) the date-time wrapped in DATE_FORMAT() it will be in the user's timezone, formatted and ready to display to the user.

Here's user-friendly SELECT for user choosing timezone:

```
<option value="Pacific/Midway">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option value="America/Adak">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii-Aleutian</option>
<option value="Etc/GMT+10">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option value="Pacific/Marquesas">(GMT-09:30) Marquesas Islands</option>
<option value="Pacific/Gambier">(GMT-09:00) Gambier Islands</option>
<option value="America/Anchorage">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>
<option value="America/Ensenada">(GMT-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California</option>
<option value="Etc/GMT+8">(GMT-08:00) Pitcairn Islands</option>
<option value="America/Los_Angeles">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)</option>
<option value="America/Denver">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)</option>
<option value="America/Chihuahua">(GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan</option>
<option value="America/Dawson_Creek">(GMT-07:00) Arizona</option>
<option value="America/Belize">(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan, Central America</option>
<option value="America/Cancun">(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey</option>
<option value="Chile/EasterIsland">(GMT-06:00) Easter Island</option>
<option value="America/Chicago">(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)</option>
<option value="America/New_York">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option>
<option value="America/Havana">(GMT-05:00) Cuba</option>
<option value="America/Bogota">(GMT-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco</option>
<option value="America/Caracas">(GMT-04:30) Caracas</option>
<option value="America/Santiago">(GMT-04:00) Santiago</option>
<option value="America/La_Paz">(GMT-04:00) La Paz</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Stanley">(GMT-04:00) Faukland Islands</option>
<option value="America/Campo_Grande">(GMT-04:00) Brazil</option>
<option value="America/Goose_Bay">(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Goose Bay)</option>
<option value="America/Glace_Bay">(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)</option>
<option value="America/St_Johns">(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland</option>
<option value="America/Araguaina">(GMT-03:00) UTC-3</option>
<option value="America/Montevideo">(GMT-03:00) Montevideo</option>
<option value="America/Miquelon">(GMT-03:00) Miquelon, St. Pierre</option>
<option value="America/Godthab">(GMT-03:00) Greenland</option>
<option value="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires</option>
<option value="America/Sao_Paulo">(GMT-03:00) Brasilia</option>
<option value="America/Noronha">(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Cape_Verde">(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is.</option>
<option value="Atlantic/Azores">(GMT-01:00) Azores</option>
<option value="Europe/Belfast">(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Belfast</option>
<option value="Europe/Dublin">(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin</option>
<option value="Europe/Lisbon">(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Lisbon</option>
<option value="Europe/London">(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : London</option>
<option value="Africa/Abidjan">(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik</option>
<option value="Europe/Amsterdam">(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna</option>
<option value="Europe/Belgrade">(GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague</option>
<option value="Europe/Brussels">(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
<option value="Africa/Algiers">(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa</option>
<option value="Africa/Windhoek">(GMT+01:00) Windhoek</option>
<option value="Asia/Beirut">(GMT+02:00) Beirut</option>
<option value="Africa/Cairo">(GMT+02:00) Cairo</option>
<option value="Asia/Gaza">(GMT+02:00) Gaza</option>
<option value="Africa/Blantyre">(GMT+02:00) Harare, Pretoria</option>
<option value="Asia/Jerusalem">(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem</option>
<option value="Europe/Minsk">(GMT+02:00) Minsk</option>
<option value="Asia/Damascus">(GMT+02:00) Syria</option>
<option value="Europe/Moscow">(GMT+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd</option>
<option value="Africa/Addis_Ababa">(GMT+03:00) Nairobi</option>
<option value="Asia/Tehran">(GMT+03:30) Tehran</option>
<option value="Asia/Dubai">(GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat</option>
<option value="Asia/Yerevan">(GMT+04:00) Yerevan</option>
<option value="Asia/Kabul">(GMT+04:30) Kabul</option>
<option value="Asia/Yekaterinburg">(GMT+05:00) Ekaterinburg</option>
<option value="Asia/Tashkent">(GMT+05:00) Tashkent</option>
<option value="Asia/Kolkata">(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi</option>
<option value="Asia/Katmandu">(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu</option>
<option value="Asia/Dhaka">(GMT+06:00) Astana, Dhaka</option>
<option value="Asia/Novosibirsk">(GMT+06:00) Novosibirsk</option>
<option value="Asia/Rangoon">(GMT+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)</option>
<option value="Asia/Bangkok">(GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta</option>
<option value="Asia/Krasnoyarsk">(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk</option>
<option value="Asia/Hong_Kong">(GMT+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi</option>
<option value="Asia/Irkutsk">(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar</option>
<option value="Australia/Perth">(GMT+08:00) Perth</option>
<option value="Australia/Eucla">(GMT+08:45) Eucla</option>
<option value="Asia/Tokyo">(GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo</option>
<option value="Asia/Seoul">(GMT+09:00) Seoul</option>
<option value="Asia/Yakutsk">(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk</option>
<option value="Australia/Adelaide">(GMT+09:30) Adelaide</option>
<option value="Australia/Darwin">(GMT+09:30) Darwin</option>
<option value="Australia/Brisbane">(GMT+10:00) Brisbane</option>
<option value="Australia/Hobart">(GMT+10:00) Hobart</option>
<option value="Asia/Vladivostok">(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok</option>
<option value="Australia/Lord_Howe">(GMT+10:30) Lord Howe Island</option>
<option value="Etc/GMT-11">(GMT+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia</option>
<option value="Asia/Magadan">(GMT+11:00) Magadan</option>
<option value="Pacific/Norfolk">(GMT+11:30) Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="Asia/Anadyr">(GMT+12:00) Anadyr, Kamchatka</option>
<option value="Pacific/Auckland">(GMT+12:00) Auckland, Wellington</option>
<option value="Etc/GMT-12">(GMT+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is.</option>
<option value="Pacific/Chatham">(GMT+12:45) Chatham Islands</option>
<option value="Pacific/Tongatapu">(GMT+13:00) Nuku\'alofa</option>
<option value="Pacific/Kiritimati">(GMT+14:00) Kiritimati</option>
```

From the array:

```
$timezone_pairs = array(
'Pacific/Midway'=>'(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa',
'America/Adak'=>'(GMT-10:00) Hawaii-Aleutian',
'Etc/GMT+10'=>'(GMT-10:00) Hawaii',
'Pacific/Marquesas'=>'(GMT-09:30) Marquesas Islands',
'Pacific/Gambier'=>'(GMT-09:00) Gambier Islands',
'America/Anchorage'=>'(GMT-09:00) Alaska',
'America/Ensenada'=>'(GMT-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California',
'Etc/GMT+8'=>'(GMT-08:00) Pitcairn Islands',
'America/Los_Angeles'=>'(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)',
'America/Denver'=>'(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)',
'America/Chihuahua'=>'(GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan',
'America/Dawson_Creek'=>'(GMT-07:00) Arizona',
'America/Belize'=>'(GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan, Central America',
'America/Cancun'=>'(GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey',
'Chile/EasterIsland'=>'(GMT-06:00) Easter Island',
'America/Chicago'=>'(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)',
'America/New_York'=>'(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)',
'America/Havana'=>'(GMT-05:00) Cuba',
'America/Bogota'=>'(GMT-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito, Rio Branco',
'America/Caracas'=>'(GMT-04:30) Caracas',
'America/Santiago'=>'(GMT-04:00) Santiago',
'America/La_Paz'=>'(GMT-04:00) La Paz',
'Atlantic/Stanley'=>'(GMT-04:00) Faukland Islands',
'America/Campo_Grande'=>'(GMT-04:00) Brazil',
'America/Goose_Bay'=>'(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Goose Bay)',
'America/Glace_Bay'=>'(GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)',
'America/St_Johns'=>'(GMT-03:30) Newfoundland',
'America/Araguaina'=>'(GMT-03:00) UTC-3',
'America/Montevideo'=>'(GMT-03:00) Montevideo',
'America/Miquelon'=>'(GMT-03:00) Miquelon, St. Pierre',
'America/Godthab'=>'(GMT-03:00) Greenland',
'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'=>'(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires',
'America/Sao_Paulo'=>'(GMT-03:00) Brasilia',
'America/Noronha'=>'(GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic',
'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'=>'(GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is.',
'Atlantic/Azores'=>'(GMT-01:00) Azores',
'Europe/Belfast'=>'(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Belfast',
'Europe/Dublin'=>'(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin',
'Europe/Lisbon'=>'(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Lisbon',
'Europe/London'=>'(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : London',
'Africa/Abidjan'=>'(GMT) Monrovia, Reykjavik',
'Europe/Amsterdam'=>'(GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna',
'Europe/Belgrade'=>'(GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague',
'Europe/Brussels'=>'(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris',
'Africa/Algiers'=>'(GMT+01:00) West Central Africa',
'Africa/Windhoek'=>'(GMT+01:00) Windhoek',
'Asia/Beirut'=>'(GMT+02:00) Beirut',
'Africa/Cairo'=>'(GMT+02:00) Cairo',
'Asia/Gaza'=>'(GMT+02:00) Gaza',
'Africa/Blantyre'=>'(GMT+02:00) Harare, Pretoria',
'Asia/Jerusalem'=>'(GMT+02:00) Jerusalem',
'Europe/Minsk'=>'(GMT+02:00) Minsk',
'Asia/Damascus'=>'(GMT+02:00) Syria',
'Europe/Moscow'=>'(GMT+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd',
'Africa/Addis_Ababa'=>'(GMT+03:00) Nairobi',
'Asia/Tehran'=>'(GMT+03:30) Tehran',
'Asia/Dubai'=>'(GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat',
'Asia/Yerevan'=>'(GMT+04:00) Yerevan',
'Asia/Kabul'=>'(GMT+04:30) Kabul',
'Asia/Yekaterinburg'=>'(GMT+05:00) Ekaterinburg',
'Asia/Tashkent'=>'(GMT+05:00) Tashkent',
'Asia/Kolkata'=>'(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi',
'Asia/Katmandu'=>'(GMT+05:45) Kathmandu',
'Asia/Dhaka'=>'(GMT+06:00) Astana, Dhaka',
'Asia/Novosibirsk'=>'(GMT+06:00) Novosibirsk',
'Asia/Rangoon'=>'(GMT+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)',
'Asia/Bangkok'=>'(GMT+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta',
'Asia/Krasnoyarsk'=>'(GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk',
'Asia/Hong_Kong'=>'(GMT+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi',
'Asia/Irkutsk'=>'(GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, Ulaan Bataar',
'Australia/Perth'=>'(GMT+08:00) Perth',
'Australia/Eucla'=>'(GMT+08:45) Eucla',
'Asia/Tokyo'=>'(GMT+09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo',
'Asia/Seoul'=>'(GMT+09:00) Seoul',
'Asia/Yakutsk'=>'(GMT+09:00) Yakutsk',
'Australia/Adelaide'=>'(GMT+09:30) Adelaide',
'Australia/Darwin'=>'(GMT+09:30) Darwin',
'Australia/Brisbane'=>'(GMT+10:00) Brisbane',
'Australia/Hobart'=>'(GMT+10:00) Hobart',
'Asia/Vladivostok'=>'(GMT+10:00) Vladivostok',
'Australia/Lord_Howe'=>'(GMT+10:30) Lord Howe Island',
'Etc/GMT-11'=>'(GMT+11:00) Solomon Is., New Caledonia',
'Asia/Magadan'=>'(GMT+11:00) Magadan',
'Pacific/Norfolk'=>'(GMT+11:30) Norfolk Island',
'Asia/Anadyr'=>'(GMT+12:00) Anadyr, Kamchatka',
'Pacific/Auckland'=>'(GMT+12:00) Auckland, Wellington',
'Etc/GMT-12'=>'(GMT+12:00) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is.',
'Pacific/Chatham'=>'(GMT+12:45) Chatham Islands',
'Pacific/Tongatapu'=>'(GMT+13:00) Nuku\'alofa',
'Pacific/Kiritimati'=>'(GMT+14:00) Kiritimati'
);
```